# Ajax filter city and neighbourhood

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

i´m not getting run my application, i select the city then i need that the dropdown show the NEIGHBORHOODS associated with the city....

this is my getNeighborhoods:

```
public function pegarBairros ($cidades = null) {
 $this->layout = 'json';
 $result = array();
 debug($_REQUEST['cidade']);
 if (in_array($_REQUEST['cidade'], array_keys($this->cidades))) {
        $bairros = $this->Cep->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'bairro'), 'conditions' => array('uf_sigla' => 'sp', 'cidade' => $this->cidades[$_REQUEST['cidade']]), 'order' => 'bairro', 'group' => 'bairro'));
        sort($bairros);         
        foreach ($bairros as $id => $bairro) 
            if (!empty($bairro)) $result[$id] = $bairro;
    } else $result[] = 'error';
    $this->set('data', $result);
}
```

and this is my ajax:

```
$('#ImovelCidade').change(function(e) {
    $('#ImovelBairro').html($('<option />').val('').text('Carregando...'));
    $.getJSON(
        "<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'pegarBairros')) ?>", 
        { "cidade" : $(this).val() }, 
        function (data) { 
            $('#ImovelBairro').html($('<option />').val('').text('Selecione'));
            $.each(data, function (chave, valor) {
                $('#ImovelBairro').append($('<option />').val(chave).text(valor));
            } );
        }
    );
});
```

this ajax call the function getNeigh...

this is my select city:

```
     echo $this->Form->input('cidade', array('label' => 'Cidade', 'empty' => 'Selecione uma cidade', 'options' => $Cidades));
```

my before filter that received city:

```
    public function beforeFilter() {

    $this->loadModel('Cidade');

    $this->cidade = $this->Cidade->find('list', array ('fields' => array('id','nome')));

    $this->set('Cidades',$this->cidade);
```

Comment: do your ajax request send..?

Comment: my ajax send request to the Controller = Pages

Comment: do you get any response or error...?

Comment: the dropdown that appears neighborhoods appear 'error' that is, it is not entering this if

Comment: Look if `data` on success function has the proper values, and if `chave` and `valor` are getting the correct values too.

Comment: Eagle and Sherin...look at my question, i update some informations, my select city and how i get her

Comment: look at the firebug console and post that.....

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: i get show some neighbourhoods, but someneighbourhoods don't show....

Comment: i fixed it! was an error in the other code